# Access server running in VirtualBox

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

I use Windows 7 but I run Linux Ubuntu in a VirtualBox.  I have installed a LAMP server on Ubuntu but I am not sure how to access it.  Right now I have my router set up to Port forward to my IP  but that IP is only good for my HOST computer.  Is there a way to forward to my Virtualized Guest OS?

Comment: Your question is off topic for Serverfault because your question isn't about a professional server/networking/desktop support environment. It may be on topic for [Superuser](http://superuser.com) but please [search](http://superuser.com/search) their site for similar questions that may already have the answer you're looking for.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/146451/how-do-i-access-a-server-inside-a-vm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Virtualbox's settings, set the machine to have a Bridge Network adapter. That means that your guest will have a proper IP address on your network and will not simply use NAT through the host. Then you can set your router to forward the port to the guest's IP.

Answer (score 0):

The default networking mode for Virtualbox is NAT. You can either configure Port forwarding in Virtualbox (as well as on your router) or using bridge mode networking where your VM guest is connected directly to the network.

See [Virtual networking](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html)